# Limit decimal places to 1 using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Either rounded or truncated:

```
<div class="my-val">1.334</div>
<div class="my-val">12.133</div>
```

Should display as

1.3

12.1

Comment: js has  a `toFixed()` method

Comment: This can also be set in js using `var number = Math.round( number * 10 ) / 10;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `callBack` function of `text` function along with `Number.toFixed()` to achieve what you want,

```
$(".my-val").text(function(_,text){
  return parseFloat(text).toFixed(1);
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yqw2h15d/)